# Product url's ends with html.html

Tags: magento2, products, migration, toplinks, product-urls

I have migrated all my products from Magento 1.9 to 2.0. All the products url's are ending with .html like html.html

sample link:  http://www/domain.com/condenser-microphone.html.html

Comment: You Still need an answer??

Answer (score 0):

You can truncate url-rewrite table again and reindex to see the result

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove all product related rewrites from url_rewrite table
2. Mass update all products in admin (select all, update, set website as default)
3. If problem still exists, run this MySQL command:

`UPDATE url_rewrite SET request_path = REPLACE(request_path, '.html.html', '.html');`

Then clear the cache.