# Why add .html.html on save product in admin after migration from magento1 to magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1

Magento adds `.html` key after product url when save the product in admin in magento 2.

Product url already have `.html` but again its added `.html` in end of product url.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably happened because you didn't mapped or had a wrong mapping of url_rewrite table in map.xml

Anyway you can fix it using sql query:

```
UPDATE {prefix}url_rewrite SET request_path = REPLACE(request_path, '.html.html','.html') WHERE {prefix}url_rewrite.request_path LIKE '%html.html';
```

[source](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135736/magento-2-1-product-urls-end-with-html-html-why)

**UPD:** 
Also check out for `Search Engine Optimization` option in admin panel. There's can be `.html.html` in `Product URL Suffix` value.

Comment: @PinkeshKuwal i was update update my answer